# PiCamera version 1.19+ available but cant get above 1.12 on Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Wonder if anybody is able to clarify for me - It highly likely i'm missing something!

I have a Pi 2 Model B with a v2 camera. All ok and working. Certain functionality however was not present i.e. 'copy_to' function as an example.

Researched and found;
- I understand 'copy_to' functionality requires at least picamera 1.12. 
- My Pi was on Wheezy (understand limited to picamera 1.10)
- Updated Pi to Jessie and 1.12 working ok

Out of interest I looked to get the latest and greatest 1.19+. Updating from Jessie picamera 1.12.

Following the doc;
http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.9/install2.html

.. but unable to get above picamera1.12 - Is this expected? A restriction on Jessie? Further release with the newer version perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: There are probably conflicting dependencies. Are you installing from sourcecode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.debian.org/releases/

Debian always has at least three releases in active maintenance: "stable", "testing" and "unstable".

### stable

The "stable" distribution contains the latest officially released distribution of Debian.

This is the production release of Debian, the one which we primarily recommend using.

The current "stable" distribution of Debian is version 8, codenamed jessie. It was initially released as version 8 on April 25th, 2015 and its latest update, version 8.7, was released on January 14th, 2017.

### testing

The "testing" distribution contains packages that haven't been accepted into a "stable" release yet, but they are in the queue for that. The main advantage of using this distribution is that it has more recent versions of software.

See the Debian FAQ for more information on what is "testing" and how it becomes "stable".

The current "testing" distribution is stretch.

### unstable

The "unstable" distribution is where active development of Debian occurs. Generally, this distribution is run by developers and those who like to live on the edge.

The "unstable" distribution is always called sid.